# converting ios 3rd party APIS to 64bit architecture

Tags: ios, iphone, 32bit-64bit, ios7.1, xcode6.1

i am new in ios development and now days working on an app that has been designed in 32 bit architecture with lots of 3rd party apis and cocopods usage in it.

As **apple** has decided to move all the apps to 64-bit architecture, i'm unable to figure out if there's any api in my code that's not following the rules and is still in 32bit architecture.

**is there any way to check that and to convert them for 64bit architecture support.**???

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lipo -info` to get the supported architectures. For example:

`lipo -info mylib.a`

Could give an output like:

`Architectures in the fat file: mylib.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64`

In this case, you see `arm64`, which is the 64-bit slice you want.

As far as upgrading your libraries, you'll need to rebuild the libraries yourself or download new versions with 64-bit support.